# Creating a reusable component of stacked doughnut chart using highcharts

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I tried creating a reusable stacked doughnut component something like this
[image]

by this code

```
   import * as React from 'react';
   import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
   
   interface StackDoughnutChartProps {
     containerId: string;
     data: number[];
     colors: string[];
   }
   
   export class StackDoughnutChart extends React.Component<StackDoughnutChartProps> {
     componentDidMount() {
       this.createChart();
     }
   
     createChart() {
       const { containerId, data, colors } = this.props;
   
       const average = data.reduce((sum, value) => sum + value, 0) / data.length;
   
       const chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
         chart: {
           polar: true,
           inverted: true,
           backgroundColor: '#303030',
         },
         title: {
           text: average.toFixed(2) + '%',
           verticalAlign: 'middle',
           style: {
             color: '#ffffff',
             fontWeight: 'normal',
           },
         },
         plotOptions: {
           column: {
             borderRadius: 0,
             grouping: false,
             borderWidth: 0,
           },
         },
         series: [
           {
             type: 'column',
             color: '#222222',
             linkedTo: 'mainSeries',
             data: data,
             colors: colors,
           },
           {
             type: 'column',
             id: 'mainSeries',
             data: data,
             colors: colors,
           },
         ] as Highcharts.SeriesOptionsType[], 
         xAxis: {
           max: 8,
           visible: false,
         },
         yAxis: {
           visible: false,
         },
         legend: {
           enabled: false,
         },
       };
   
       Highcharts.chart(containerId, chartOptions);
     }
   
     render() {
       return <div id={this.props.containerId}></div>;
     }
   }
```

I don't want data to be passed in this component, as the data and colors will be passed from the parent component that it is rendered.

I passed the data and  colors as

```
const chartData: number[] = [20, 70, 80, 60, 100, 40];
const chartColors = ['#a78d34', '#2c71b8', '#1f6b6a', '#f8c601', '#36c35d', '#ffffff'];
```

and rendered it as

```
<StackDoughnutChart containerId="container1" data={chartData} colors={chartColors} />
```

But instead of the result I want, I got

[image]

something like this. Can anyone please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Highcharts API we can read:

> **colors:** Since 3.0.0
>
> A series specific or series type specific color set to apply instead
> of the global colors when colorByPoint is true. Defaults to undefined.

As a solution, enable `colorByPoint`:

```
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      ...,
      colorByPoint: true
    }
  }
```

As a side note, I recommend you to use the `highcharts-react-official` wrapper, which makes it much easier to use Highcharts in React: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7L04bsk1/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.colors

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.colorByPoint